# Algorithm to identify Combinations for success Probability

Tags: algorithm

1) Say i have 300 models with 200 different settings to predict the 
monthly sales of an item X in a market based on global GDP, FX, competitors growth, new product launches, upcoming products and many other conditions.

2) The models evaluate sales for each month for the past century and update their entries in DB. Say, in DB we have columns Model_name, Settings, Factors_Considered, Success_Probability.

3) As the data evaluation has occurred on past data, the models success/failure percentage
could be identified and updated in DB. Say, probability of sales growth of a model X PC in March by 10% is 0.8

4) However, No model is perfect (Probability of 1) and every model is true to a certain extent, considering the factors it has considered it. Say one model considers GDP where as other model considers Exchange rates and another model considers new products growth in the sector.

5) Considering all factors into one model is ultra complex, super confusing, time consuming and testing time for all combinations is painful. :(

6) The wisest decision is to use combinations of data based on the models. Say, if Model X probability is 0.7 and Model Y probability is 0.8. Then evaluate the past combinations of such data and come up with a realistic figure to estimate the future probability.
I have considered only 2 models in this example, however in real time, the combinations might exceed 5000.

7) However the saddest part being, i couldn't deduce any programming logic on how to attain this? Any suggestions/references are highly appreciated. The reader is free to consider either C/C++/Java/C# while making any programming references.

Please note, this problem could probably be considered as an extension of Knapsack problem.

Request you to do not down vote. The question seems presented in a round robin fashion, but not. If you feel any of the sections aren't organized or needs to be elaborated, please comment accordingly. Thank you.

***Clarifications sought***

**Difference between "settings" and "factors_considered"?**

Let me better try to present the differences with an example. 
Say, A model X calculates the monthly increase or decrease in sales of MC Donald's burger.

**Factors Considered**

The model X considers the following factors.

1. A factor considered could be the number of new brands entering into
   ready made food space.
2. Number of holiday's in the current month. More holidays, probability of more sales & vice versa

These metric's could be directly procured from other sources or agencies with greater accuracy. These are considered as a factors.

**Settings**

However all information couldn't be couldn't be procured directly. But we project these values based on past data. As we are projecting, we get multiple outputs.

Say Inflation for one month based on past 5 years is 0.2%
But Inflation for one month based on past 3 years is 0.4%
But Inflation for one month based on past 1 years is 0.1%
We cannot consider only the long term stats, or we could consider only the short term stats. Remember, everything moves in cycles. 
The same could be the case for unemployment rate, % of child population, etc.

The evaluation of data is performed based on inflation value of 0.2%, 0.4% on  0.1%. These three are considered as settings for the model and the required projections are made.

Now, we have the model values from both definite sources and projected factors. But which combinations work often? The combinations could comprise of data from 20 or 100 models. and each model might have 2 or 20 settings.

Comment: Could you clarify what the difference is between "settings" and "factors_considered"?

Comment: Also just to check my understanding, does #6 mean you want to figure out the optimal weights for N models given their probabilities, or make a new model based on the N other models?

Comment: Altered the question accordingly, to address your comments. The last paragraph addresses this point. Thank you.

Comment: Never expected such a poor responses from Stack overflow :(. Guys, please suggest something. Nothing's wrong. Gimme idea's.